# SQLite: unable to use PRIMARY KEY (sqlite3.OperationalError)

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert, primary-key, create-table

I'm trying to create a `PRIMARY KEY` with `sqlite3` but I get an error.

Code:

```
import sqlite3


class DataBaseManager:
    
    
    def __init__(self, database):
        
        self.database = database
        self.tablevideos = "videos"
        self.cols = (
                "idkey INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
                "name INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                "uploaded INTEGER DEFAULT NULL"
            )
        self.defaults = {
                "uploaded": None
            }
        self.insertcols = "?,?"
        self._create_database()
   
   
    def _create_database(self):
        """
        Creates the database if it does not exist
        """
        
        connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = (
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            "{}({})".format(self.tablevideos, self.cols)
            )
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
    
    
    def insert(self):
        
        connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = (
            "INSERT INTO {} "
            "VALUES ({})".format(self.tablevideos, self.insertcols)
            )
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            data = [
                i,
                *self.defaults.values()
                ]
            cursor.execute(query, data)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

databasemanager = DataBaseManager("data.db")
databasemanager.insert()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\FileTagerPy\example.py", line 59, in <module>
    databasemanager.insert()
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\FileTagerPy\example.py", line 53, in insert
    cursor.execute(query, data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table videos has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
```

If I remove `"idkey INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "` it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you provide 3 values when inserting values within the table? I see that there. is only 2 elements considered here `self.insertcols = "?,?"`

Comment: @rafidini primary keys do not count for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list the names of the columns `name` and `uploaded` that will receive the values of the inserted row.

In `__init__` add one more line:

```
self.insertcols = "?,?"
self.insertcolnames = "name,uploaded"
self._create_database()
```

and in `insert`:

```
query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(self.tablevideos, self.insertcolnames, self.insertcols)
```

This will return the statement:

```
INSERT INTO videos (name,uploaded) VALUES (?,?)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider adding an "id" column to your table and setting it as the PRIMARY KEY. You can do this by using the "ALTER TABLE" command.

Additionally, you should ensure that the id is set to autoincrement or use the "MAX()" function to find the next available id and assign it as the primary key.

Comment: Why? `idkey` is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Camille, please look https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/